# Tengo 2 activity_main pero al darle run me alza el primero como lo cambio para el segundo

Tags: android-studio

Hola amigos soy nuevo en android , quisiera que me ayudaran a como decirle android q me habra la segunda actividad no la primera .[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"></activity>
</application>
```

Donde cambiaria este es mi android manifest

Comment: Holas @KevinQuevedo, acostumbra agregar el código o layouts como texto en lugar de imágenes para que sea más útil tu pregunta a otros desarrolladores ya que pueden emular el problema que expones, además en ocasiones las imágenes de código o layouts no se ven bien, Saludos.

Comment: gracias amigo , intento darle run a la actividad 2 y me sale the activity that must exported

Comment: Kevin, agrega por favor tu AndroidManifest.xml a tu pregunta. @KevinQuevedo

Comment: Gracias @KevinQuevedo revisa la información de la respuesta y al final esta el cambio en tu archivo.

Answer (score -1):

Define dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` el [intent-filter](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) adecuado para que la `Activity` que desees sea la primera en cargarse, en este caso este sería el [intent-filter](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html):

```
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Por ejemplo si deseas que inicie `MainActivity2`, quitalo a `MainActivity` y asignalo a `MainActivity2`:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity2">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

de esta forma `MainActivity2` sería la primera `Activity` en cargarse de tu aplicación.

---

Para ser más especificos este sería el cambio en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: gracias , me explicas que hicistes por favor!!

Comment: Esta explicado en la respuesta, solo asigna el intent-filter con action Main y category launcher.

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.